# If $f \in L^1(m)$ and $F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f(t)dt$, then $F$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, continuity

I am in the middle of trying to prove problem 2.26 from Folland's Real Analysis: "If $f \in L^1(m)$ and $F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f(t)dt$, then $F$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$."

In order to prove this, I am trying to find some sequence of complex-valued functions $\{f_n\}$ such that $f_n \rightarrow f \chi_{(-\infty,x]}$, where $\chi_{(-\infty,x]}$ is the indicator function on $(-\infty,x]$, in order to use the Dominated Convergence Theorem. I have started with letting $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence of elements of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $x_n \rightarrow x$, and I have also defined $f_n = f \chi_{(-\infty, x_n]}$. The problem is that I am not sure what the limit of $f_n$ is: is it $f \chi_{(-\infty, x)}$ or $f \chi_{(-\infty,x]}$? Furthermore, since the requirement in the Dominated Convergence Theorem is that $f_n \rightarrow f \chi_{(-\infty,x]}$ almost everywhere, does it even matter which is the actual limit?

Comment: Whether $(-\infty,x]$ or $(-\infty,x)$ is irrelevant, you only need convergence _almost everywhere_, and $\{x\}$ is a null set.

Comment: I would consider going a different route. Since $f\in L^1(m)$, given $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for all measurable sets $A\subset \Bbb R$, $m(A) < \delta$ implies $\lvert \int_A f\, dm\rvert < \epsilon$. So for all $x,y$, $\lvert x - y\rvert < \delta$ implies $\lvert F(x) - F(y)\lvert = \lvert \int_y^x f(t)\, dt\vert < \epsilon$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a sense the very definition of $F$ is a bit ambiguous since before knowing about continuity you might want to specify if $x$ is included or not. On the other hand since $\{x\}$ has measure zero it doesn't matter.
Suppose you define $F(x) = \int f \chi_{(-\infty,x]}$.
Then if $x_n>x$ converges to $x$ we have 
$$ F(x_n)-F(x) = \int f \chi_{(x,x_n]} \rightarrow 0$$
by dominated convergence and pointwisse convergence to zero
 Similarly if $x_n<x$:
$$ F(x_n)-F(x) = -\int f \chi_{(x_n,x]} = -\int f \chi_{(x_n,x)} \rightarrow 0$$
using in addition the above-mentioned $m(\{x\})=0$.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please explain why $\int f\chi_{(x,x_n]}\to 0$?

Comment: @Koro He did: "by dominated convergence and pointwisse convergence to zero".

Comment: @AnneBauval: yes, but how was point wise convergence used there? How was $\int f\chi_{(x,x_n]}$ made small?

Comment: @Koro Mere application of the DCT: since $f\chi_{(x,x_n]}\to 0$ (pointwise) and $|f\chi_{(x,x_n]}|\le|f|\in L^1,$ $\int f\chi_{(x,x_n]}\to\int0.$

Comment: @AnneBauval: I see. Thank you so much. Put differently, $g_n:= f\chi_{(x,x_n]}$. $g_n(t)\to 0$ for all $t$ and then DCT.

Comment: Yes (not "differently")